# How can I create folder on localhost using jQuery and insert imageData as Image at that folder?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I **create folder** on **localhost** using jQuery and insert **imageData** as Image at created folder?

My localhost directory is

> E:\xampp\htdocs\trinity_app\desktop\BAT\res\images\deliver\

I want to create a new folder in this directory. Folder name  `\new_folder`.

Comment: you mean only using jquery ? without php ?

Answer (score 1):

you can not create folders by jQuery. jQuery is a JavaScript library that can not write to your filesystem. It would be a huuuge security risk to allow JavaScript to write to your system. 
For such tasks, a server-side script language like PHP is just perfect. If this actually was your question...please modify it and have a look at the other answer posted here. On the client-side, there gladly is no way to do so by JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can make a directory,

```
if (!file_exists('path/to/directory')) {
   mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```